# How do I make two LabelFrames align with each other?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two tk.LabelFrame widgets which should be equal when it comes to width. I have tried to fine-tune each of the widgets (and the widgets inside), but nothing worked out so far. It's either too much, or too little. For instance, 14 is too little, and 15 is too much, and 14.5 is not accepted (of course).

[image: GUI]

Current code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

material_label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root)
material_label_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

material_label = ttk.Label(material_label_frame, text='Material:')
material_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

material_combobox = ttk.Combobox(material_label_frame, width=15, values=['Gold', 'Silver'])
material_combobox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)

weight_label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root)
weight_label_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

weight_label = ttk.Label(weight_label_frame, text='Weight:')
weight_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(5, 14), pady=5)

weight_entry = ttk.Entry(weight_label_frame, width=11)
weight_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

weight_combobox = ttk.Combobox(weight_label_frame, width=3, values=['g', 'kg', 'oz'])
weight_combobox.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(0, 5), pady=5, sticky=tk.W)

root.mainloop()
```

I would really appreciate it if someone helped me overcome the issue.

Comment: When you say "14 is too much", 14 _what_? Padding? Width?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't really have one thing in particular in mind, and 14 could have been any number, as well. I've tried changing both padding and width, had no success. The one thing I have not really thought of is using tk.W+tk.E (although I oftenly use it in my GUIs), so thanks for your help once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sticky="ew"` to get the frame to fill the column. If both frames are in the same column and both use the same `sticky` value to stick to both sides of the columns, they will align up precisely.

```
material_label_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
weight_label_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
```

Comment: Indeed, this fixed the problem the way I expected. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **place** function instead **grid** function. Place is more complicated, but let you be more precisely in your design interface.

Like this:

weight_entry = ttk.Entry(weight_label_frame, width=11)

weight_entry.place(x=10, y=75, width = 120)

Comment: How do you know a width of 120 is the right width? The problem with place is that you need to know the size of the fonts being used, and you may also need to know the resolution. `place` is rarely the right choice.

Comment: The "width = 120" was just an example. I am not doing the project, is just a suggestion. For the problem given, I see the place function as a POSSIBILITY to solve the problem, even if it is rare. I also used in all my project and it worked very well (https://github.com/rafaelcalixto/PortfolioManager2).